# How to get started with OpenGL on Mac OS Sierra?

Tags: c++, macos, opengl

I've been trying to get started with OpenGL on Mac.

I tried this:

[Hello Triangle OpenGL 4](http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/hellotriangle.html)

which resulted in this error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_glDepthFunc", referenced from:
>   _main in main.cpp.o
>   "_glEnable", referenced from:
>   _main in main.cpp.o
>   "_glGetString", referenced from:
>   _main in main.cpp.o

I tried following this tutorial : [Opening a Window | OpenGL](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-1-opening-a-window/)

which result in this error:

```
Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.
```

but clearly Intel HD6000 supports OpenGL 3.3

[image: OpenGL Extension Viewer Screenshot]

the error has been discussed in FAQ as well which states this reason:

> other possible reason is that you’re on a Mac, with a pre-Lion version.

but I am on Sierra.

What am I missing?

Comment: For the linking errors, try adding `-framework OpenGL` to your linking command.

Comment: Regarding outdated tutorials, https://open.gl/ is a great up-to-date one. There's lots of discussion in the comments if you're having issues.

Comment: @Max thanks for the link. It was a great help.